# Run Java Code without a package in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, java-package

I want to run my code without creating a package in java eclipse IDE.

But when I do so it is showing [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcrma.png) :

```
Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module 'Games'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which requires not to use the default/unnamed package.

In the default package **delete the file `module-info.java`** to not use JPMS and to be able to have code in the default package.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the project folder -> New -> Package. Once the package is made, move all your classes into it.

Comment: but I don't want to create any package ... I want to make it default !!!

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the error icon at the line number ->move to default package option.

Make sure the classes are (public or protected) to be used in different packages.

Comment: sry bro ... didn't get it ! Can u explain please ?

Comment: When you remove the package statement from your code, eclipse shows error on the line number right? When you double click the error symbol, it also shows the suggestions to correct the error. Among them, choose "move to default package" option

Comment: but i doubled click on error symbol but it showing nothing !

Comment: Try keeping the mouse pointer on the error symbol without clicking on it and see if it suggests. In my eclipse ide it does.

Comment: sry bro nothing happen !

Comment: Adding Snapshots might help.

Comment: Im sorry. Im not accessible to my laptop right now. Create the class directly inside the default package. Use project explorer. Right click on default package -> new class. You can find package explorer here: menu bar-> Window->Show View->Other...->Java-> project explorer

Comment: i have given a screenshot.. hope u will help

Answer (score 0):

In the file in question, right click to get the context menu. Select "Refactor->Move". The resultant dialog will have the (default package) into which the source file may be placed.

Also, be sure to not have a package definition line at the start of the source file.

Please note that the use of the `default` package is generally discouraged, but there are time I still use it (primarily for printing copyright/version information).

[image]

[image]

There are also options for turning on hidden/suppressed parent packages, but I think the Refactor approach is the most clean.

Answer (score 0):

The most viable answer to this problem is to remove the module-info.java file located on the Project Explorer tab of Eclipse. This file is created by default. Also, deleting this will not affect your program. Hope this will help.